# not unable to adding android platform using cordova3.3

Tags: cordova

I am getting error while adding android platform using the following command

```
cordova platform add android
```

I have already setup all the environment variables,

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;D:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;D:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

But its giving error like this:

```
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project.
at C:\Users\vishnuvardhan.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:244:30
    at exithandler (child_process.js:633:7)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:649:5)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **windows OS:**

1. instal ant , and add path to environment var
2. add android sdk/tools path to environment var
3. instal node js , and instal phonegap (npm install -g phonegap)
4. type phonegap create HelloWorld com.example.hello "Hello World"
5. cd HelloWorld.
6. **phonegap local build android**

**in MAC OS**
1. add android sdk/tools  path to .bash_profile
and try

more info plz check [link](http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html)